# Replacing and removing leading characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query
`Select Distinct EMPLOYEE_ID from TABLE` 
and this returns bunch of EMPLOYEE ID's with leading zero's if the person's ID starts with 000 then it should be an 'e' and if it's 00 then it should be a 'u'
so for example if I have 
0041258 this should show in the result as u41258 and if I have 
00041258 then this should show as e41258
Is there a way to trim and replace in more efficient way that using substr and Case statement? and if no can you please show me how to use the substr and the Case statement in this case

Comment: Do you need a query, for reporting, or do you need to actually modify the data stored in the table (on disk)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `case`:

```
select (case when employee_id like '000%' then 'e' || substr(employee_id, 4)
             when employee_id like '00%' then 'u' || substr(employee_id, 3)
             else employee_id
        end)
```

I doubt there is a much more efficient method than this.

Answer (score 0):

Option that uses nested regular expressions:

```
SQL> with test (id) as
  2    (select '0041258'  from dual union
  3     select '00041258' from dual
  4    )
  5  select id,
  6    regexp_replace(regexp_replace(id, '^000', 'e'), '^00', 'u') result
  7  from test;

ID       RESULT
-------- --------------------
00041258 e41258
0041258  u41258

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to write an `update` statement (to permanently change the id's):

```
update <table>  
  set   employee_id = case when employee_id like '000%' 
                             then 'e' || substr(employee_id, 4)
                           else   'u' || substr(employee_id, 3) end
  where employee_id like '00%'
;
```